# Image scale won't work with \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, chemstyle

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemstyle}

\begin{document}
    \begin{scheme}[ht]
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{schemes/lab1}
        \caption{Experiment 1 reactions and mechanism}
    \end{scheme}
\end{document}
```

When I don't use `scale`, this MWE works fine. However, when I use `scale`, I get the errors:

```
Runaway argument?
scale=0.8]{schemes/lab1} \caption {Experiment 1 reactions and mechanism} \end {scheme} 
/Users/Zak/Documents/McGill/CHEM 222/TSWLatexianTemp_001549.tex:16: Paragraph ended before \Gin@iii was complete.
```

and

```
\begin{document} ended by \end{scheme}.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try including `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the preamble.